# SQOOP Export from HIVE to Oracle table fails randomly

Tags: oracle, export, sqoop

While running SQOOP Export, failing as 
**ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column**
We tried splitting data and SQOOP it & we could able to see rows which are failing. Again if we try to export only failed rows, it's getting exported successfully. 
We itierated up to failing row, again its failing in different row.
When we tried SQOOP EXPORT to Oracle.
All Rows ---1689105
Failed in between as value larger than specified precision allowed for this column. 
So added row_id and found 172200 exported successfully.
Again when export rows 172200 & 172201 it went successfully.
So splitted HIVE table upto 172200 and above 172200.
When exporting 172200 rows it failed 172177. 
When exporting above 172200 rows it failed in 452729.
When inspecting rows individually also not able to locate any error with data.
SQOOP Statements used.

Error log below,

```
2016-12-07 06:53:14,691 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: 
2016-12-07 06:53:14,691 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: Exception raised during data export
2016-12-07 06:53:14,691 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: 
2016-12-07 06:53:14,691 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: Exception: 
java.io.IOException: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:233)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlRecordWriter.write(AsyncSqlRecordWriter.java:46)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:658)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:84)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1707)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:58)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:943)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeForRowsWithTimeout(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10932)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:11043)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:244)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AsyncSqlOutputFormat$AsyncSqlExecThread.run(AsyncSqlOutputFormat.java:231)
2016-12-07 06:53:14,692 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: On input: 172177JACOB IZBICKI & CO. LTD101726825708\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N10.0\N\NNo PremiumNo Premium\N0.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.02343750.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.0\N\N0.00.00.00.00.00.00.01905.00.0No Data2005-05-25 00:00:00.02007-05-26 00:00:00.0\N2.02.0Low0.0Low1.32Low0.0LowNONEIncrease price to drive to profitabilityNULLNULLNULLNULLNULLNULLNULLNULLNULLNULLNULLNULL\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N\N0.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.0
2016-12-07 06:53:14,692 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: On input file: hdfs://dnvdevbigdata2.corp.nai.org:8020/user/hive/warehouse/mcafee_masterdatabase.db/wc_output_clv_detail_mdmparent1/000000_0
2016-12-07 06:53:14,692 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: At position 82909184
2016-12-07 06:53:14,692 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: 
2016-12-07 06:53:14,692 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: Currently processing split:
2016-12-07 06:53:14,692 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: Paths:/user/hive/warehouse/XXXXXX.db/XXXXXXX/000000_0:0+67108864,/user/hive/warehouse/mcafee_masterdatabase.db/wc_output_clv_detail_mdmparent1/000000_0:67108864+15820814,/user/hive/warehouse/XXXXXX.db/XXXXXX/000002_0:0+67108736
2016-12-07 06:53:14,692 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: 
2016-12-07 06:53:14,692 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: This issue might not necessarily be caused by current input
2016-12-07 06:53:14,692 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: due to the batching nature of export.
2016-12-07 06:53:14,692 ERROR [main] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper: 
2016-12-07 06:53:14,692 INFO [Thread-11] org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper: Auto-progress thread is finished. keepGoing=false
```

SQOOP Statements used.

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@odevbi-XXXXXXX:1521/XXXXX \
-username YYYY -password YYYY123 \
--table TEST_TABLE \
--input-fields-terminated-by '\001' \
--lines-terminated-by '\n' \
-m 1 \
--input-null-non-string "\\\N" \
--input-null-string "\\\N" \
--direct \
--export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/yyyyy.db/xxxxx
```

Comment: Why don't you just Google for `ORA-01438` and try to understand what it means? It's not a Sqoop issue, it's a developer issue. Just use the appropriate precision/scale in your Oracle `NUMBER` column definitions.

Comment: Thanks Samson for your advise. We have got some 190 columns that includes both VARCHAR & NUMERIC fields. So, finding it difficult to identify the column(s) having this precision problem because, even the logs(pasted above) don't show the column name(s). I'll check this ORA-01438 and see if i can find out any other way to figure out the corrupt column(s).

Comment: You know which row(s) are generating the error message, so you can generate manually an Oracle *INSERT VALUES* query, and force the numeric values to NULL one by one until the *INSERT* is good. Then you will know which column was the issue.